# Why does MediaCodec.reset() generate java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: android-mediacodec

[The official document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec) says: "Call reset() to make the codec usable again. You can call it **from any state** to move the codec back to the Uninitialized state."

However, the following code occasionally throws java.lang.IllegalStateException:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    //do nothing
} else {
    try {
        mediaCodec.reset();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
          //occasionally throws java.lang.IllegalStateException
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Class: java.lang.IllegalStateException
 Stack trace: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaCodec.native_reset(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaCodec.reset(MediaCodec.java:1794)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are right, the documentation is a bit misleading here because there are two possible states a MediaCodec instance can be in that are not resettable.

If the MediaCodec instance is released, Released state, it is obviously not resettable thus resulting in an IllegalStateException.

If the MediaCodec instance is in Error state because it could not be created it is also not resettable, but this time resulting in a MediaCodec.CodecException. For example if you create to many instances.

[A comment](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libstagefright/MediaCodec.cpp#1295) in the libstagefright sourcecode describes what a reset call is basically doing.

```
    /* When external-facing MediaCodec object is created,
       it is already initialized.  Thus, reset is essentially
       release() followed by init(), plus clearing the state */
```

If you check out the code you'll see that when release is called on an already released MediaCodec instance it'll result in an INVALID_OPERATION err, which leads to the codec not being reinitialized and ultimately in an IllegalStateException.

I hope this clarified your question

Best regards

Chris

Comment: Thank you for the elucidation.  I have been looking for a way to check the state. Actually, I was just about to ask how to check the state on SO with another question. Do you know if this is possible? I have been trying my best to avoid resetting a MediaCodec after it is released.  I set an MediaCodec to null immediately after it is released, but I can imagine situations where checking null still misses it because there are so many different threads using MediaCodec.  I up-voted your answer, and will accept it if no better ones come up.

Comment: Sadly, there is no way to check the state that i know of. It seems that the state is only stored in native code and never exposed. What i did a while back was intorducing my own state and wrapped it in a wrapper class. But it's not perfect either because you sometimes won't get notified about some errors.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.   Deriving a class from MediaCodec is exactly what on my mind now.  Dealing with hardware codec is very tricky. Nothing can be guaranteed because some hardware codecs are flaky,  I think at least the derived class can help tracking an app's own actions.